# KeyError "[.....]" not in index

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am working on a project for work and was handed this code after having no previous experience with Python. I'm getting a KeyError message, and the line above that has some red text that I am also unsure about. Here's the exact text:

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))

KeyError: "['First name' 'Last name' 'Company' 'Email address - other' 'Opened At'\n 'Company.1'] not in index"
```

I have been looking into tutorials all day and understand that this is an issue with the fact that this DataFrame doesn't have an index, but I think that is due to the fact that it is importing data from a file that doesn't have a set name.

Here's the beginning portion of the code that I believe has the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob, os
import re

# In[21]:
db = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob("report_*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    db = db.append(df,ignore_index=True)

# In[22]:
db= db[['First name','Last name', 'Company', 'Email address - other','Opened At','Company.1']]

# In[23]:
db.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in db.columns]
db.columns = [c.replace('-', '_') for c in db.columns]
db.columns = [c.replace('.', '_') for c in db.columns]
```

When I print(bd) I get this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

So I recognize that I need to add an Index but I'm not sure what it should be. The resulting file should have 6 columns, I believe, but the number of rows varies.

I am willing to provide whatever information is necessary I'm just at a loss of what to do and would appreciate any help at all!

Edit: Print(df.head()) yields:

```
print(df.head())
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-873aa293d964>", line 1, in <module>
    print(df.head())

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: After `df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")` do you get anything from `print(df.head())`?

Comment: Please post an example of what the csv file looks like

Comment: @roganjosh when I do that I get this: 
  File "<ipython-input-15-873aa293d964>", line 1, in <module>
    print(df.head())
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: @EdekiOkoh would you like a sample of the CSV itself or once it's in excel?

Comment: Yes that would be fine, thanks. In the future any data related question should have some data associated with it so we can recreate the bug

Comment: @EdekiOkoh how do I give you the sample? I am totally lost.

Comment: Copy the output of df.head and post it to your question

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Added

Comment: Did you print df after you use read_csv? It shouldn't be empty is there is data being read from the file.

Comment: You've called your dataframe `db` not `df`

Comment: you should have done `print(db.head())` instead of `print(df.head())` as you have stored the dataframe as `db`.

Answer (score 1):

**All the COLUMN are having a space "Opened At", we have an extra space in "Opened At". We need to get rid of it.**

> df= pd.read_csv(fileName)
>
> df=df.rename({"Opened At":"Opened_At"},axis=1)

**Hope this will solve your problem.**